# sort simplexml array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, sorting

I have this simplexml array which i managed to get working from examples on google. now i have to sort the array.

this is what i have.

```
$url = 'http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Member/2128687/Listings/All.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->List->Listing as $list){
echo $list->EndDate;
echo '<br/>';
}
```

everything works as it should like that. i want to sort it by closest to end date.

ive tried all the examples i can find and i just keep getting white screen of nothing.

please help!

Comment: please paste `var_dump()` of this array too!

Comment: the entire array? its pretty large lol

Answer (score 0):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $a = strtotime($a->EndDate);
    $b = strtotime($b->EndDate);
    if ($a == $b) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($xml->List->Listing, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
```

Comment: but probably you should copy this array and working on other array not from this object

Comment: you comment doesnt make sense to me.. im a noob at coding. can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

using [usort](http://php.net/usort)

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

        $listingarray = (array)$xml->List;
        $listingarray = $listingarray['Listing'];


    function compare($obj1,$obj2)
    {   
        $time1 = strtotime($obj1->EndDate); 
        $time2 = strtotime($obj2->EndDate); 

        if($time1 == $time2)
            return 0;

        return ($time1 > $time2 ? -1 : 1);
    }

    usort($listingarray,'compare');



        foreach($listingarray as $list)
        {
            echo $list->EndDate . '<br />';
        }
    ?>
```

if your php version >= 5.3 you can write the compare function inline as a parameter..

```
usort($listingarray,function($obj1,$obj2)
    {   
        $time1 = strtotime($obj1->EndDate); 
        $time2 = strtotime($obj2->EndDate); 

        if($time1 == $time2)
            return 0;

        return ($time1 > $time2 ? -1 : 1);
});
```

Comment: what would the next step be if i wanted to have 3 options of sorting. sort by enddate (closest first), by isfeatured (true to be first. the order of the isfeatured will still be by closest to enddate), and by lowest price?

Comment: convert Listing to an array(recursive) and try this solution, to sort https://gist.github.com/1220785